# Django not receiving new query string when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

AJAX call is not sending new query-string to views.py. The call is successful, but  database doesn't update with results. I guess I am calling to nothing? How do I make query string reach the views.py? Everything works fine if I take away `.preventDefault()`. I am pretty sure there's something I need to edit in my views.py.

html:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
<input id='foo' type='text' name="search" value="{{ request.GET.search }}"/>
<input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //stop submit
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{% url 'index' %}",
                data: $('#foo').val(),
                success: function(data){
                        // alert($('#foo').val());
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

views.py

```
def page(request):
    stuff = model.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get("search")
    if query:
        stuff = stuff.filter(
            Q(field__icontains=query)

            )
    context = {'stuff': stuff,
    }
    return render(request, 'app/page.html', context)
```

> **UPDATE**

I did some digging and this [link](https://www.fir3net.com/Web-Development/Django/how-do-i-use-ajax-along-side-django.html) helped explain things a bit further. I basically had to create a  SEPARATE view that contained everything `page` had. This new view had the 'logic', processed the ajax request and spit out results, which I then told my AJAX call send to a div. Don't forget to make a url for the new view as well. This is where you need to send the ajax request to.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the parameter name `search` in the `data:` option.

```
data: { search: $("#foo").val() },
```

Comment: this for some reason isn't working. Any reason why? Are you sure there's nothing I need to add to my views.py?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Django. But I don't see why anything special would be required. This sends the parameter in exactly the same way that it gets sent if you do a normal form submission instead of AJAX. And you said that the form works when you take out `.preventDefault()`, which causes it to submit the form normally.

Comment: Do you have code in the `success:` function that displays the returned HTML in the DOM?

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification. One final question: the `url` piece is currently set to send the request to itself (the same page). Maybe I should be sending it to a specific part of the page? Thanks again for your response.

Comment: Yes I do, it is set to display a hidden div that will expose the query results (a table). The main problem I have is the refreshing, and refreshing hides the div again.

Comment: The code for the page needs to check at the beginning whether it's being used to process the form or display the initial page. Maybe that part is automated by Django, I don't know. I usually prefer to use separate scripts for display and AJAX processing.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your last comment, but I used `console.log` so that I can see the output, and it simply displayed the entire HTML as the response. I don't think it's sending the data. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about debugging Django code. Is there some way you can `print(query)` to see if the parameter was received?

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I needed to create another view (or empty html page) that contained the database entries. I then sent the AJAX request to that page, and it returned results. I then directed the tuple to a div and wrapped it around a table table w/ a loop statement (1 row for ea. entry). The html and ajax part was spot on. Thank you for your help.